# what does folders inside .cache/pip/http do or for what?

Tags: http, pip, storage

My computer suffers from `not enough storage`. So I am looking for the folders that I can delete without any issue that can break my system. I came accross with `.cache/pip/http` folder.There are many folders that every one of them at least 2 Gib. I couldn't find an explanation for the following questions in my mind.

What is the purpose of these folders?

What would be the result if I delete them?